# How to add Menu option before the icon app option in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the position of option in action bar, to appear before the application icon.

Comment: I want to give answer... but what you have to tried ?

Comment: @Hardik man if you have answer just post it i am also interested

Comment: @Hardik be sure that I have tried a lot and still trying. so please if you have an answer share it with us  ..

Comment: But main thing is what is problem???